# ASP.NET MVC 2 projects don't recompile?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2, msbuild

I have this *very* strange issue with my MVC 2 project. Often times, I'll edit some code and there will be a compile error. If I hit F5 to debug, the error *goes way* even though it isn't resolved. I usually don't notice this and I then keep working, hitting F5 to debug and get extremely frustrated when my changes don't show up and when my breakpoints can't be hit (how do I know there is something wrong when there are "no" errors). I did this for *hours* today. Doing a rebuild all on the solution doesn't help, only build/rebuild on the MVC project.

Worse, it's intermittent and if it goes away, I have no idea how to reproduce it. I can't make it happen on a new solution so I think maybe there's something wrong with my solution. It's got half a dozen projects but no special build steps or anything like that.

Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. I needed one project to compile as x86 for interop reasons, and somewhere in that process the build option for my MVC project got unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

I run into an error building a MVC 2 project after I've published it.  I can't just build it. It needs to be rebuilt.  Not sure if this is the same type of issue you are seeing.